# Not able to post to friends wall with facebook sdk in ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I have tried with openGraph and normal dialog as below,

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",@"friends_fb_id" ] andParams:variables andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`

and

`[facebook  dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]`

I gave params for both methods as

`NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"friends_fb_id", @"to", 
                                   @"I'm using the Hackbook for iOS app", @"name",
                                   @"Hackbook for iOS.", @"caption",
                                   @"Check out Hackbook for iOS to learn how you can make your iOS apps social using Facebook Platform.", @"description",
                                   @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/", @"link",
@"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];`

in delegate method it correctly return the Post_id, so its completing successfully but I can not see the post on friends wall. If try using the Hackbook app that comes with SDK it works perfectly.

What could be the possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to enable `publish_actions` or `publish_stream` permissions during login?

```
// login to FB
-(void) FBLogin
{
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream", nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *_session, FBSessionState _status, NSError *_error) {
        //  do some login handling code here
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the string "friends_fb_id" should this not be an actual id?

I had a similar situation where is was receiving the correct response, so it was posting, it was just posting to the wrong place.
Make sure the id's are correct.

Comment: yes I am giving the correct id in code, in above question 'friends_fb_id' is for display purpose only ;)